# personal.unlockAccount() Error: Invalid JSON RPC response and crashes Geth

Tags: go-ethereum, console

It's launch of Geth:

```
geth --testnet --fast --rpc --verbosity 0
```

The start of interaction with console:

```
geth attach ipc:/.../geth.ipc
```

Console works great but when I inputs the following command:

```
personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], "psw", 0)
```

(different parameters: with/without duration, "eth.coinbase" or just adress name instead of eth.accounts[0], etc)

console is blocked for several minutes. At the same time Geth does not work for all sessions, RPC is disable. Finally it returns

> Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: {"error": {"EOF":"EOF",
>   "code":-32603}, "id":11, "version":"2.0"}

Geth process is killed.

What is it?

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3996/error-personal-unlockaccount-method-not-implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable personal API on the command line:

```
   geth  --rpcapi eth,web3,personal,admin
```

[More info](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs)

However be aware that if you expose RPC socket to public Internet and personal API is exposed anybody can steal your Ether.

Comment: Also sounds like your geth instance has not synced blockchain fully yet - that might cause slowdowns on less powerful computer.

Comment: I do not know why (all these modules were plugged) but it solved my issue.